# Using len() as an argument of an update statement

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Is it possible to run an update like

```
update products set title = name+' - '+ id where len(name+' - '+id)  <  255
```

In mssql?

I have been trying to update a text field but I can't do this if the results would have more than 255 characters.According to our shopping cart provider.

**EDIT:**
Sorry I didn't specify what I am looking for that well, I have tried it and am getting an error saying the results would be truncated. I guess what I'm really asking is there a way to accomplish what I am trying to do in the example of trying to only update if the update data is shorter than 255 characters.

Comment: What error you are getting? you tried it?

Comment: I have tried it, and I'm getting an error saying that the results would be truncated.

Comment: What is the size of title?

Comment: 255 characters when I checked. But I've been told by the company hosting our business site that they have it limited to 240 to 250, and I have tried  less but getting the same issues.

Comment: Can you post your table structure with some sample data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code should work unless the title field really isn't 255.  [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/dfaf5/1)  Here's what I did and it worked.

```
create table #temp 
(
    name varchar(20),
    Title varchar(20),
    id varchar(3)
)

Insert into #temp
SELECT '1111111111', '', 100
UNION 
SELECT '111111111111', '', 101
UNION 
SELECT '11111111111111', '', 102
UNION 
SELECT '1111111111111111', '', 103
UNION 
SELECT '111111111111111111', '', 104


UPDATE #temp
SET title = name+' - '+ id 
WHERE len(name+' - '+id)  <=  20


SELECT * FROM #Temp
```